# Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise. IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2

I have finished my asp.net mvc 4 web application and want to publish on my server. I know mvc 4 needs IIS 7.5.

I have windows server R2 enterprise installed on my machine with IIS 7.0

Does it possible to update IIS 7.0 to 7.5?

If it not does it possible to install 7.5 on R2?

Please provide iis 7.5 download link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install IIS 7.5 on your Server 2008. But this won't be a problem. MVC 4 is compatible with IIS 7.0